# Can someone explain exactly what is happening with single quotes and double quotes with process IDs in the below example?

Tags: bash, process

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $$
16991
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c "echo $$"
16991
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c "echo $$"
16991
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c 'echo $$'
21062
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c 'echo $$'
21063
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c 'echo $$'
21064
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c "echo $$"
16991
```

I understand that whenever we use single quotes, a new sub-shell is created, and same is not happening with double quotes. Why is it so?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6697781/3776858)

Comment: The important and tricky part is the handling of the `$$` here - so these above are not duplicates.

Comment: Since nobody else has stated this explicitly, as far as I can see — `bash -c …` _always_ creates a sub-shell (i.e., a new process) regardless of the type of quotes used. The quoting style affects only _what command_ that sub-shell is asked to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:**  The shell performs parameter substitution on strings in double quotes but **not** on strings in single quotes.  `$$` is the shell PID but the number you see depends on *which* shell evaluates it.

**Details:**  Let us consider each case, one at a time.

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $$
16991
```

16991 is the PID of the current shell: let's call it the main shell.

```
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c "echo $$"
16991
```

When main shell sees `"echo $$"`, it will substitute in 16991 for `$$`.  Thus, the string passed to `bash -c` will be `echo 16991`.  That is why 16991 is printed.

```
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c 'echo $$'
21062
```

Because `'echo $$'` has single quotes, the main shell does not do parameter substitution.  The string `echo $$` is passed to `bash -c`.  21062 is printed because it is the PID of the the `bash -c` process.

```
[root@localhost ~]# bash -c 'echo $$'
21063
```

The next time that you run the `bash -c` process, it has a new PID, this time 21063.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are strong quoted, which bash will read as parameters, instead of a string as double quotes are intended for.  Invoking bash with the -c option will tell it to use non-string parameters as positional parameters.  Since single quotes are not strings, they must be interpreted as positional statements.

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bash-options.html